# Lan cable passes cable tester but doesnt work (partially)

Tags: ethernet, rj-45, cabling

So I bought brand cat 7 roll from amazon with good reviews (dont need cat7 in this particular case just want to connect a 2 meter cable @ 100mbps)

How I connected the ends

1st pin orange stripes
2nd pin orange
3rd pin green stripes
4th pin blue
5th pin blue stripes
6th pin green
7th pin brown stripes
8th pin brown

My cable tester passes the cable as working (so both ends of the tester light up simultaneously and in series starting with the same number 1-1,2-2,3-3 etc)
I also tried my multimeters continuity test manually with probes all pins of the ends seem fine
First time I plugged it in it worked!

but then it stopped working... like on its own.. I didnt move or bend the cable etc.

I did the tests again all seems fine, but the computer now doesnt even detect the cable and the lights are off.

The computer's lan port (and the router's ) must be ok since testing them with a couple of retail cables of various sizes yield 0 issues.

What could it be? (the cable is brand new and also has a metal net around the foil shielded cables and on top of that I didn't touch the cable so I doubt it got scratched or anything)

Is this something common ? Cheap cabling? I cant explain why this happens.

Comment: Is the cable solid or stranded, and how did you terminate it (jacks or sockets?)     You may have intermittent connectivity issues if you used the wrong type of connector for the cable.   Also, can you link to the cable you purchased. One would not normally use Cat7 cable for a 2 meter patch cable which needs to work at 100 megabits - indeed you are better off with cat6.

Comment: @davidgo the cables are solid. I terminated them with rj45 shielded plugs https://nimbus-screenshots.s3.amazonaws.com/s/f3d5e7c8c8f302cac2191039aca23775.png The cable I bought is this https://www.amazon.de/-/en/BIG680-BIGtec-All-Patch-Cables/dp/B005Q0SVW8/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=cat.7-kabel&qid=1613524643&sr=8-5 and it came with the plugs (not in this offer but you can see them on the "frequently bought together" section, as for why cat7 ? I bought it for an other use but just happen to need a 2 meter ethernet cable and this roll was what I had around.

Comment: Don't know!  Bad crimp maybe? (ie maybe the wires didn't go all the way to the end).  I'm out of my depth here, but it seems very weird to me that they are selling solid core cable for patch leads.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
I put new connectors on the cable and tested the cables with a cable tester.
The cable tested ok. But when I put the cable in the modem, no connection at all.
I put a switch between the new cable and the modem, and all works fine.
The seems like the connectors I used are not compatible with all devices, which caused the problem.